# I am trying to build a program in JavaScript that scans a paragraph and returns the sentences that contain specific words

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is this the right way to go about it or should I try a different method?
Suggestions, corrections, and constructive criticism welcome.
**I got to the point where I can identify certain words, now I need to log the whole sentence the word was in to the console. Please Help**

**

```js
<html>
<head>
 <title> Program</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var names = "hello hi welcome dills pills deaths kills thank you bye five";
 names = names.split(" ");
 var userInput = prompt("Enter Paragraph");
 userInput = userInput.split(" ");
 for (var i = 0; i < userInput.length;  i++) { 
  for (var x = 0; x < names.length; x++) {
   if (userInput[i] == names[x]) {
    console.log(userInput[i])
   }
  }
 }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I propose this short code wich seems to match your requirement :

```
var names = "hello hi welcome dills pills deaths kills thank you bye five";
var names = names.split(" ");
var userInput = "Hello friends. It is cold today. I was born in Australia. I am twenty five";
var results = [];
names.forEach(el => userInput.toLowerCase().split(".").forEach(element => {if (element.includes(el)) results.push(element)}));
console.log(results); // [ 'hello friends', ' i am twenty five' ]
```